# Local diffeomorphism that is also a homomorphism of Lie groups

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

Let $G$ and $H$ be two Lie groups with the same Lie algebra $\mathfrak g=\mathfrak h$ and let $f:G\to H$ be a Lie group homomorphism that is also a local diffeomorphism. I claim that the differential map at the identity $d_ef:T_eG\to T_eH$ is the identity map of $\mathfrak g$, however, I am not able to prove it.

Is my claim true?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try some examples, like $G=H={\mathbb R}$?